# How do I isolate the "Join Clan" button on Bungie.net to use on our clan website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For a more descriptive usage:

On our Bungie.net clan page, Bungie has two processes to go through.

One is "request join" which can be found on the clan page website, and then "set as playstation" clan follows after (if logged in as PSN).

This may be closely related to reverse engineering, which may be frowned upon, but we only want to isolate the element and figure out some type of POST method in which users can visit our website, and then simply click the "request to join" button, and they'll automatically send in their request.

Here's an example:

Clan:
http://www.bungie.net/en/Clan/Forum/612223

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlB3C.png

I've been trying to figure this out for two days now, and I can't find anything to possibly use here.

I'm sure it's more javascript based than anything, but even doing a carbon copy of the entire site (which has external javascript URL's, and I can curl those, so it's authorizing my servers' usage of the javascript files).

Any help would be seriously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow. Do you want to restrict the button to people browsing the website on Playstation? If so, you're looking for $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].